# How to get key press keyboard source in hotkey hook in Python?

Tags: python, keyboard, hook, low-level

I have to create program, which react to f3, f4 and q press from specific keyboard without focus. I have to handle 2 things:

How to detect on which keyboard it was pressed.
How to detect Q press. VK does not contain letters.
I have connected 2 keyboards over USB and I need to react only for one keyboard. How to get key click source keyboard? Thank you for help I really need this.

My actual code: https://hastebin.com/enomowesof.properties

Comment: Stack Overflow questions need to be self-contained, with the code you're asking about being small enough to fit right in the question in a code block.  You *can* link to a full project, but you do still need to include directly any code you're directly asking for help in fixing, or that's essential for showing how you're currently doing something.  Also, what OS?

Comment: @PeterCordes I know, but there was some problem while adding code to a question, so I put it to hastebin. I am using Windows